# Как правильно обратиться к классу в моем случае (BEM)?

Tags: html, css, бэм

Написал для наглядности часть меню с выпадающим списком, хочу понять следующее:

1. Верно ли написаны классы, если брать в расчет BEM?

   ```
       <li class="item">
           <a class="item__link">123</a>

           <ul class="dropdown">
               <li class="dropdown__item">
                   <a class="item__link">123</a>
               </li>
           </ul>

       </li>

   </ul>
   ```
2. Правильно ли так обращаться к классу исходя из BEM?

   .container-menu .container-menu__list > .item {}

   .container-menu .container-menu__list > .item > .dropdown > .dropdown__item {}

Comment: ВЕМ как раз и был создан для того, чтобы не было вложенности.

Comment: @Александр можно пример в моем случае, как сделать все 'идеально' по BEM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="dropdown__items">

    <li class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">        
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown__items">        
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: а тут не получается элемент в элементе?